# MySQL - The DBMS must maintain a separate execution domain for each executing process

Tags: mysql, security

I'm trying to get a government system hardened and during that process I have to answer certain criteria. One of them is the below:

> Rule Title: The DBMS must maintain a separate execution domain for
>   each executing process.
>
> Discussion: Database management systems can maintain separate
>   execution domains for each executing process by assigning each process
>   a separate address space. Each process has a distinct address space so
>   that communication between processes is controlled through the
>   security functions, and one process cannot modify the executing code
>   of another process. Maintaining separate execution domains for
>   executing processes can be achieved, for example, by implementing
>   separate address spaces.
>
> Check Text: Review the DBMS architecture to find out if and how it
>   protects the private resources of one process (such as working memory,
>   temporary tables, uncommitted data and, especially, executable code)
>   from unauthorized access or modification by another user or process.
>
> If it is not capable of maintaining a separate execution domain for
>   each executing process, this is a finding.
>
> If the DBMS is capable of maintaining a separate execution domain for
>   each executing process, but is configured not to do so, this is a
>   finding.
>
> Fix Text: Deploy a DBMS capable of maintaining a separate execution
>   domain for each executing process.
>
> If this is a configurable feature, configure the DBMS to implement it.

Anyone have any information or documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer depends on how you define the term "process".

MySQL is a single-process DBMS; each connection runs as a separate thread, but they [share the same process address space](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-use.html). Subsequently, there's nothing that prevents one thread from accessing another thread stack, for example.

In the *spirit* of the rule text you quote MySQL is "not capable of maintaining a separate execution domain for each executing process" -- if by "process" you understand a client connection.

However, if you stick to the *letter* of the rule, since there's only one DBMS process at the OS level, no isolation is necessary apart from the process isolation provided by the underlying operating system.